# Rstudio shiny not able to use ggvis

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have an RStudio Shiny server running and I installed ggvis from https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis but I am not able to reproduce any of the demo examples in the server.

When I run R with the same version installed in the server (3.1.0), I can do the following:

```
> library("shiny")
> library("ggvis")
The ggvis API is currently rapidly evolving. We strongly recommend that you do not rely on this for production, but feel free to explore. If you encounter a clear bug, please file a minimal reproducible example at https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues. For questions and other discussion, please use https://groups.google.com/group/ggvis.

Attaching package: "ggvis"

The following object is masked from "package:stats":

    filter

> ggvis::ggvisOutput
function (plot_id = rand_id("plot_id")) 
{
    ggvisOutputElements(plot_id, spec = NULL, shiny = TRUE)
}
<environment: namespace:ggvis>
```

But when I try the example in one of the demo folders:

```
# ui.R
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  div(),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("n", "Number of points", min = 1, max = nrow(mtcars),
                value = 10, step = 1),
    uiOutput("plot_ui")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    ggvisOutput("plot"),
    tableOutput("mtc_table")
  )
))

# server.R   
library("ggvis", lib.loc="/opt/R/R-3.1.0/lib64/R/library")))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # A reactive subset of mtcars
  mtc <- reactive({ mtcars[1:input$n, ] })

  # A simple visualisation. In shiny apps, need to register observers
  # and tell shiny where to put the controls
  mtc %>%
    ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    bind_shiny("plot", "plot_ui")

  output$mtc_table <- renderTable({
    mtc()[, c("wt", "mpg")]
  })
})
```

I get:

`ERROR: could not find function "ggvisOutput"`

Commenting out the line with the `ggvisOutput` statement then renders the page normally but with no plot.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to put the `library("ggvis")` line at the top of the ui.R file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Source `ggvis` in your `ui.R` file (example here `http://128.199.255.233:3838/userApps/john/ggvistest/`):

## ui.R

```
library("ggvis")
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  div(),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("n", "Number of points", min = 1, max = nrow(mtcars),
                value = 10, step = 1),
    uiOutput("plot_ui")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    ggvisOutput("plot"),
    tableOutput("mtc_table")
  )
))
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # A reactive subset of mtcars
  mtc <- reactive({ mtcars[1:input$n, ] })

  # A simple visualisation. In shiny apps, need to register observers
  # and tell shiny where to put the controls
  mtc %>%
    ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    bind_shiny("plot", "plot_ui")

  output$mtc_table <- renderTable({
    mtc()[, c("wt", "mpg")]
  })
})
```

Comment: You quote `ggvis` in the `UI.R` call, is this correct? `library("ggvis")`

Comment: I have been trying to follow this example but it keep receiving the error "ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer". Does anyone know what causes this error?